# How can I build the attached circuit diagram in a bread board?

Tags: power-electronics, solenoid

How can I build the attached circuit diagram in a bread board? I've procured all the mentioned components.

[image: Solenoid connections]

The components I have are:

1. BLM5 Solenoid,
2. Vishay 100V 3A rectifier diode,
3. Welwyn 39Ω wire-wound resistor,
4. Small bread board (not the mini),
5. Tiny push button.

Comment: Breadboards are not meant for Amps of current.

Comment: Breadboards also aren't meant to be used for 230VAC circuits.

Comment: What @StainlessSteelRat said. You cold consider to just panel mount the components if they are made for it an run wires. The diodes could be soldered standing to the switch terminals if this is just a test setup and not for mass production.

Comment: This is one of those "bad idea but good thing you asked" questions

Comment: When you write "tiny push button", do you mean an (On)-Off-(On) switch? That's what is meant in the circuit diagram; here are some examples from [Farnell](https://cpc.farnell.com/c/electronic-electrical-components/switches-relays-solenoids/switches-accessories/rocker-switches?switch-operation=-on-off-on-).

Answer (score 11):

1. Breadboards aren't made for amperes of current.
2. Breadboards aren't made for 230VAC.
3. The switch in the diagram is a single pole, double throw, center off, momentary contact switch.  It is not a simple push button.
4. It is almost guaranteed certain that the pins of most of the components will not fit in the holes on a standard breadboard.

- The circuit belongs in an insulated box to protect you from the 230VAC connections on the transformer.
- You will need to solder the connections.  Most of the components will have leads or lugs to solder to.
- The switch will have to be rated for 2 amperes, just like the diodes.